# How to install appy.io?

Tags: python, pip

Trying to add

`from appy.io import get_target_file`

and keep ending up with Module not Found error and can't figure out how to install the libraries I need correctly. I've already done `pip install appy` and that was successful. Does anyone know how to get appy.io working?

Comment: What's the output of `pip freeze | grep appy` as well as `python3 -m pip freeze | grep appy`?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation you're following? There is an [`appy`](https://appyframe.work/tool/public) package, but it doesn't have an `appy.io` module (nor does it have a `get_target_file` method anywhere).